# Oracle: query with 'N' function - which datatype should I use?

Tags: oracle, types

I have created an Oracle table with an indexed varchar2 column, called 'ID'.
A software I'm using is reading this table, but instead of running queries like

```
select * from table_name where ID='something'
```

it does (notice the extra "N" before the value)

```
select * from table_name where ID=N'something'
```

which is causing some kind of character conversion.
The problem is that, while the 1st query is performing a range scan, the 2nd is performing a full table scan.

Since I cannot modify the queries that this software is running, which data type should I use, instead of varchar2, so that the conversion performed by the 'N' function does not imply a full table scan?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The prefix N before the string is used to specify a NVARCHAR2 or NCHAR datatype.

When comparing NVARCHAR2s to VARCHAR2s, Oracle converts the VARCHAR2 variable to NVARCHAR2. This is why you are experiencing a FULL SCAN.

Use a [NVARCHAR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45685) column instead of a VARCHAR2 in your table if you can't modify the query.